# Miss inpout file @androidsdk//:build-tools/26.0.1/aapt when compiling tensorflow android demo with bazel

Tags: android, linux, tensorflow, bazel

I want to compile the Tensorflow Android demo in Ubuntu with Bazel

[image]

I also tried this command after searching but another error occurred:

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1`

[image]

I changed WORKSPACE file buildtools to 26.0.2,and the result of compilation is as follows:

[image]

What I can do?

Comment: What is the `path` attribute of `android_sdk_repository` in your `WORKSPACE` file set to? If it's set to nothing, what is `$ANDROID_HOME` set to?

Comment: the **path** attribute is set to a SDK which is installed with AndroidStudio.and the **$ANDROID_HOME**  is set to the same file

Comment: what is the result of `ls $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/26.0.1`?

Comment: I changed `WORKSPACE` file buildtools to 26.0.2,and the result of compilation is as follows:

Comment: sorry I don;t know how to insert a image. I tried `Ctrl`+`G`,but it didn't work

Comment: I edited the question again,hope for your help

Comment: Based on the latest screenshot, it looks like you solved the build-tools problem. It looks like you have a second problem related to the NDK. I'd suggest you open a new issue for that one. (My guess is that your NDK is too new. Bazel only supports up to NDK14.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use path names with ASCII characters only. I'm not sure Bazel works correctly with paths that contain non-ASCII characters.
2. Make sure you installed the Android SDK.
3. Open `/home/fancy/AI/tensorflow/WORKSPACE` in an editor, and make sure that:

   - the `android_sdk_repository` and `android_ndk_repository` rules are uncommented (don't have a `#` before them), and
   - these rules have a [`path` attribute](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/android.html#android_sdk_repository), which specifies the absolute path to the Android SDK and NDK, respectively

Comment: or, instead of the `path` attribute, check that `$ANDROID_HOME` and `$ANDROID_NDK_HOME` environment variables are defined correctly.

Comment: yeah, I did all these things